# Switch pro controller not detected by bluetooth on windows 11

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, windows-11

I have a switch pro controller. This controller works fine on my PC (windows 11) in wired mode. However, when I try to put the controller in pairing mode and connect the controller to my PC via bluetooth, the controller does not appear under the "add a device" menu.

How do I troubleshoot further?

I have tried restarting my PC